Push changes from web server to Github (BitBucket)
I am a developer who works on multiple sites and have added them all to repos in Bitbucket and use visual studio/GIT Gui to push my development changes to the repo. On these sites, the site owner can also make changes to files and these site owners don't use the repos. It is really beyond their capability- they are busy running their ecommerce site.
The boss wants me to make sure the repos have the lastest updates on the site. In order to do that, I have to download the files via ftp and then upload them to the repo and I usually use Git Gui to do that rather than open each one in Visual Studio.
I don't normally have systems admin permissions to the servers. Is there a way to set the sites to update to the repo automatically? I know this type of procedure is backwards from the way Git us normally used/supposed to be used, but it is what it is.
Thanks
